# Visual C# 2015 Form error when moving from 2007 to Win 8

Tags: c#, forms, compatibility

This is a C# winforms project.

This has been driving me crazy for over a week.  It would be difficult to show the code, because most of it is generated by visual C itself and it would be quite long.

I have a form quite quite a few controls.  The form and the program work just fine on my desktop.  When I move to my laptop, which has a lower resolution and which is windows 8, the form, which is taller than the window.

This happens even if I resize the form programatically to fit ahead of time.  The form will fit inside the laptop resolution, but half of it would be cut off just as if it ran off of the edge of the screen.

It is important to note,t hat when I set the resolution of my desktop down to the same level as my laptop I so not have this problem.  The only different that I can think of is that my desktop is running 2007 and my laptop is running Windows 8.  I have tried this on two different win 8 laptops with the same result, but my program has worked on multiple desktops.  I do not have a laptop with high enough vertical resolution to contain the form before it is resized via the program.

Is there anything windows 8 does differently in this regard?  If so, is there anything I can do to fix it?  I am baffled--but it is very important that this program work on my laptop.  I designed it to help grade papers, and I need to be able to take it with me.

There are so many controls for my program it would be more than a major undertaking to try to resize them all so that they would fit, by default, at a lower resolution.  This is winforms, and because of the way they are laid out grabbing them all and resizing makes half of the controls disappear.

Has anybody else had this problem when moving a program with a large form from win 7 to a win 8 laptop?

Sorry this post is so long, but since it was not reasonable to post the code, I wanted to give a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me before. What I did was make sure the laptop was in its highest resolution (best quality). Then I played with the resolution to get a close fit. If the resolution is 1228x790 then make sure your form is half the size.

The OS has nothing to do with it. It's a monitor to monitor ratio. Base your app on the laptop resolution instead of the desktop. Then with it smaller you can always maximize the form with the maximize button on the form.

Just be sure to anchor everything properly.

I hope this helps. This is what I always do.

Comment: But when I set the resolution down on my desktop monitor it works?

The problem is that the program is written.  I can't really start over.  Reformatting all of the controls....there are hundreds...

Comment: I have tried to set the autoscroll for the form to on.  This works to allow me to scrool a too-large second form that the first form opens, but but the primary form--the one that opens when the program starts, has controls that run off the right hand side and the bottom and the autoscroll bar never appears.  This would not be a perfect fix but it would help... but for some reason even this does not work.

Comment: It's not the resolution of the monitors. It's in the from properties. If the laptop screen resolution is 1080x720 and your form has a size of 1500x1200 then the program will be set for 1500x1200. So if you put it on the screen that is 1080x720 the form will be cut off because you have it to show 1500x1200 by default. So you will have to set the form properties on the form to 800x500 for it to show properly on the 1080x720. Your form size can not exceed the laptop screen size if it does exceed it in the form properties then it will always maximize to what you have set in the form properties.

Comment: Why I am trying to determine is why the program behaves differently on my desktop monitor when set to 1080x720  than it does on my laptop which also has that resolution.  Again, I have code that will scale down the form controls to all fit if the screen resolution is too small, but this only works when I set my desktop monitor resolution down to any size I want.  It doesn't work on the laptop's native resolution.

I did resolve the autoscroll problem--evidently the autoscroll does not activate if a tab control goes past the edge of a form.

Comment: Are you setting the form size or are you changing the monitor resolution?

Comment: I was changing the monitor resolution to test the form.

I put in code to scale the form and controls down to fit whatever size resolution it is on, but that only works correctly on the desktop comp.  New forms opened by program scale properly, but the main/default form is cut off on the laptop.

I managed to get the scroll-bar to work.  That seems to be a "good enough " solution in that I can now scroll down to see the contents (mostly--it still doesn't look quite right on the laptop).  It is just baffling to me.  Unfortunately with all the scaling code, it is just to big to post.

Comment: Try this. Look at your laptop screen resolution. Lets say its 1080x720. Now go to your desktop, open your project. Click the form properties. Scroll down until you see the form size. In the form size put 800x500. Everything will look jumbled. But it will fix itself on the laptop. I develop on a monitor that's 32". Normal size form is the form size. If the form size is bigger than the laptop resolution then it will be cut off. If its smaller then it will fit perfectly.

Comment: Thanks to those who helped.

I have no idea why this question was down-voted.  It was entirely legitimate and I searched for answers first.  Some people are petty.